# how to use both And and Or condition in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

Run Keyword

```
 If      '${Contains_True}' == 'true'
     and
'${App_Name}' == 'App Name' 
     Accept_Confidential
  ELSE IF     '${Contains_True}' == 'true' 
"Do Something"    ELSE     Log    "Nothing"
```

Comment: what's the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the below examples the different combinations are tested against a keyword that validates the combinations using the and/or validations. Please keep in mind that this kind of and/or check can also be separate `ELSE IF` statements.

```
*** Test Cases ***
TC
    [Template]    Validate App and Contains
    App Name       true
    App Name       false
    My app Name    true
    My app Name    false 
    Not My Name    true
    Not My Name    false 

*** Keywords ***
Validate App and Contains
    [Arguments]    ${App_Name}    ${Contains_True}    
    Run Keyword If 
    ...    ('${Contains_True}'=='true' and '${App_Name}'=='App Name') or '${App_Name}'=='My app Name'    Return From Keyword     Accept
    ...    ELSE IF     '${Contains_True}'== 'true'    Log    App Name is not as expected:"${App_Name}"    level=WARN    console=${True}
    ...    ELSE        Fail    Of the combo "${App_Name}"/"${Contains_True}" None of the values are correct.
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer Mr A.Kootsta. It works fine.